# How to set value of cell in List<int[][]>?

Tags: java, arrays, list, multidimensional-array

I have a list `List<int[][]> orgnisms = new ArrayList<>();`, which I have populated a few empty (only 0 values) tables and I want to set the value of certain cells now. For example, I want the first table from list and cell `[1][1]` to have a value of `1`. How do I accomplish that?

EDIT:

I have a problem because `orgnisms.get(0)[1][1] = 1;` adds the value `1` to each table in list, not only table which has index `0`...

Here is my code to generate a new empty multi-dimensional array which then gets added to the `orgnisms` list:

```
private void newEmptyArrays(){
        int[][] emptyTable = new int[n][n]; 
        for( int[] ii : emptyTable) 
            for (int i : ii)
                i = 0;

        for(int i=0;i<mi;i++)  
            orgnisms.add(emptyTable);

}
```

Comment: `identifier.get(0)[1][1] = 1;`

Comment: `List<int[][]>  = new ArrayList<>();` ? no identifier

Comment: @Aominè Add answer to get 'solved'

Comment: `for (int i : ii) i = 0;` does absolutely nothing. If you want to zero out the array, you need to do `for (int i = 0; i < ii.length; i++) ii[i] = 0;` or `Arrays.fill(ii, 0);`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
List<int[][]> orgnisms = new ArrayList<>();
```

each element within the list is a multi-dimensional array, hence if you want to access any of them you'll first need to retrieve it through the `List#get` method then perform some operations on it i.e

```
orgnisms.get(0)[1][1] = 1;
```

`orgnisms.get(0)` will retrieve the reference to the multi-dimensional array, then `[1][1]` will index into row `1` and column `1` of the retrieved multi-dimensional array and assign a value `1` to it.

**Update**

> I have a problem because orgnisms.get(0)[1][1] = 1; adds the value 1
>   to each table in list, not only table which has index 0...

Look carefully at your last loop, you're storing multiple references to the *same* multi-dimensional array within the `orgnisms` list thus it makes sense for such behavior to happen.

Also, as per your update, the code is not doing what you think it's. In fact, the nested `for` loops are *not* doing anything to the `emptyTable` multi-dimensional array. However, by default, all the arrays inside `emptyTable` have a value of `0` set to each element anyway, meaning *attempting* to set them to `0` again is *redundant*.

That said, you can change your method accordingly:

```
private void newEmptyArrays(){
      for(int i = 0; i < mi ; i++){  
         int[][] emptyTable = new int[n][n]; 
         orgnisms.add(emptyTable);
      }
}
```

Comment: I have problem because identifier.get(0)[1][1] = 1; add value to each table in list, not only table which has index 0...

Comment: look at my edit. Can it makes that each table set same cell?

Comment: @Xalion see my update. keep me updated with anything else.

Comment: I wrote down `orgnisms.add(new int[n][n]);`  and it started adding to certain table( not each one)!

Answer (score 1):

The same 'table' is being added multiple times to the list, but it is just the only one 'table' that was created in following code part (original problem, not the solution):

```
int[][] emptyTable = new int[n][n]; 
for(int i=0;i<mi;i++)  
    orgnisms.add(emptyTable);
```

since there is only one instance multiple times, there is no difference by which index of the list the table is being changed. `orgnism.get(0)` is the same (instance) as `orgnism.get(1)` and so on...

Solution: create a new 'table' for each entry in the list:

```
for(int i=0;i<mi;i++) {
    int[][] emptyTable = new int[n][n];
    orgnisms.add(emptyTable);
}
```

and just a note, the assignment in following code part is not changing the value inside the array - it wouldn't work to clear an array:

```
for (int i : ii)
    i = 0;  // this only changes the value of the variable, 
            // not of the array entry (not written back)
```